# Update query for two different Column in two different table-MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on upwork type project and want to create an update query for bids.
User has free bids (which he gets by default per month) and pro bids which he can buy for certain amount.
Now if he would apply on any job then I want to update `-1` for job_quota (if it is not 0 already), then `-1` from pro bids in ascending order.

My table structure (in user table):

**users**

```
job_quota -------->id

12---------------->53
```

**Buy_bids**

```
id---->no_bids--->amount_paid--->user_id 

1-----> 20------------>20---------------> 53

2-----> 20------------>20---------------> 53

3-----> 20------------>20---------------> 53
```

I have an idea like this - but I do not how to implement it into MySQL query:

```
$query=<<< SQL
update users set job_quota=job_quota-1 if ( job_quota !=0 )
else update buy_bids set no_bids =no_bids-1 where user_id=53
SQL;
```

Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve it, I am not looking for accurate solution but I need your help and suggestion what should I try to achieve this.

Many Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to update two tables there?

Comment: try it by using 'case' statement for if else....

Comment: Is there any common column in these two tables?

Comment: there is  `user id` is common, but there `column` name is not common... @Crazy2crack

Comment: yes you are right ...@Dinesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something Like this?

```
Update users ,buy_bids 
set users.job_quota = case when users.job_quota !=0 then 
                                users.job_quota-1
                      else users.job_quota end,
    buy_bids.no_bids =case when users.job_quota =0 then 
                                 buy_bids.no_bids-1
                     else buy_bids.no_bids end
WHERE users.user_id=buy_bids.user_id        
and users.user_id=53;
```

This is not tested. Just a suggestion. I'm not sure about the else condition,so just added `users.job_quota =0` . Change that accordingly.

Comment: But it is updating all rows in buy_bids for particular user. I just want to update only single rows based on date, means old date will update and so on.... By the way thanks...

Comment: you can add that condition in the `case`

Answer (score 1):

This is my proposal:

```
UPDATE users
    IF (job_quota NOT IN 0 )
    THEN  SET job_quota = -1
    ELSE (UPDATE buy_bids SET no_bids = no_bids -1 
          WHERE users.id = 53)
WHERE id= 53
```

Comment: It is throwing this error `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (job_quota NOT IN 0 ) THEN SET job_quota = job_quota-1 ELSE (UPDAT' at line 2`

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->query('
    update users 
    set job_quota=job_quota-1 
    where job_quota != 0 
      and user_id=53
');

if ($stmt->affected_rows == 0) {
    $mysqli->query('
        update buy_bids 
        set no_bids =no_bids-1 
        where user_id=53
    ');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggetion, but I am looking for it only by mysql query without using php... @Matei